# Linq outer Join

Tags: c#, linq

How do I change this query to an outer join so that customers with no orders still appear in the results?

```
Customers
                   .Join(
                      Orders,
                      c => c.ID,
                      r => r.ID,
                      (c, r) =>
                         new
                         {
                             Name = c.Name,
                             Address = c.Address,
                             OrderNumber = r.OrderNumber,
                             OrderDetails = r.OrderDetails
                         }
                   ).ToList()
```

Comment: Have you tried the samples at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from c in context.Customers     
join o in context.order on new { cid = c.cid } equals new { cid = o.cid } into ljoin
from l in ljoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new()
{
  //whatever
};
```